# Django AdminSite overrides admin template

Tags: python, django

I tried to complete Django tutorial and it says that you can override Django's templates with providing example on how to change title of admin page ([here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial07/#customizing-your-project-s-templates)). When I tried, nothing changed, so I went to google and investigate.

My project structure currently looks like this (django_trial is my project's name):

```
- django_trial/
    - django_trial/
    - polls/
        - ...
    - templates/
        - admin/
            - base_site.html (copy of template from Django with modified title)
        - base_site.html (copy of admin/base_site.html from above, just in case)
    - venv
```

I tried to see what template it loads, so I put code below in my polls/admin.py

```
from django.template.loader import get_template

a = get_template("admin/base_site.html")
print(repr(a.origin))
```

and it printed
`<Origin name='/home/my_username/Projects/django_trial/templates/admin/base_site.html'>`, so my template override seems to work somewhat correctly.

Then I tried modifying actual library files and changing original `.../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html` didn't do anything as well.
In the end, I managed to change admin page title when I modified `.../venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py`. There is a class `AdminSite` and it has the line

```
site_header = gettext_lazy("Django administration")
```

Seems it has top priority, so its modification actually changed admin page title.
What could I do wrong so this line always take priority?

**EDIT**: ok, I got a little confused. Modifying that AdminSite attribute obviously works the same both in library files and if I import and change attribute value in some project file. However, by tutorial it seems the template overriding should work as well, so the question stands.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a few things:

**Add template path in settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')], # <- add this line
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},]
```

To **update admin header** you can do it using the admin model provided by django

just add:

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.sites.AdminSite.site_header = "YOUR ADMIN HEADER"
```

Comment: Yes, I have this line added, as in tutorial. I know that I can change this property, but I wanted to get template overriding to work to make sure it will be possible when I will need it in my project somewhere else